# How is Capistrano related to Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rake, capistrano

I'm starting to read up on Capistrano after using Rake tasks to deploy apps for a long time. It's really striking how similar it is to Rake. A lot of parallel commands (like `cap -T`) and a lot of identical concepts (namespaces, tasks).

Does anyone know the history behind that? Is Capistrano an extension of Rake, or built on top of it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [Capistrano v3 switched back to using a Rake DSL](http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html) instead of rolling their own [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

---

[Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) v1 and v2 had no dependencies on [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/).  It was written from scratch as a DSL for handling remote servers.  It's evident that some aspects of capistrano were influenced by rake, but [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/) felt it was necessary to make capistrano stand on its own.  Capistrano tasks behave slightly differently than rake tasks and their hookable nature separates them from rake tasks.

Capistrano has received minor criticism for not building upon rake, but it is still the most popular deployment tool at least in the rails community.  Other projects such as [Vlad the Deployer](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html) counter capistrano's implementation by using rake and ssh directly.

Comment: Is this answer still actual?

Comment: @Nakilon I just updated the answer to reflect something more accurate now that time has passed, and Capistrano v3 changed directions.

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano started out as a series of Rake tasks but went indie early on in its development.